# How to add description lines to the header of a .txt output in R

Tags: r, export, dataframe

I'm trying to create a .csv or .txt file from a `data.frame` object that also contains some lines describing more detail about the variables.

Here's my first attempt:

```
Head <- "
#variables:
#sal - Salinity [PSU]
#temp - Temperature [degrees Celsius]
"

n <- 10
df <- data.frame(sal=runif(n, 30, 37), temp=runif(n, 15, 17))
df

sink("data.txt")
Head
df
sink()
```

which results in this:

```
[1] "\n#variables [units]:\n#sal - Salinity [PSU]\n#temp - Temperature [degrees Celcius]\n"
        sal     temp
1  32.11494 15.35176
2  30.57537 16.80972
3  32.90651 15.95174
4  30.62192 15.73436
5  31.43069 15.45873
6  34.38173 15.69713
7  31.27954 15.01126
8  32.77093 16.22493
9  35.99510 15.10123
10 35.52409 15.49084
```

but, I would really like it to look like this:

```
#variables [units]:
#sal - Salinity [PSU]
#temp - Temperature [degrees Celcius]

        sal     temp
1  32.11494 15.35176
2  30.57537 16.80972
3  32.90651 15.95174
4  30.62192 15.73436
5  31.43069 15.45873
6  34.38173 15.69713
7  31.27954 15.01126
8  32.77093 16.22493
9  35.99510 15.10123
10 35.52409 15.49084
```

Comment: Or, if you don't want to use `sink()`, `fn <- "data.txt";  writeLines(Head, fn); write.table(df, fn, append=TRUE, quote=FALSE)`

Comment: @JoshO'Brien - Thanks for another great approach - maybe consider creating another answer below. If you wouldn't mind, I have a followup question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21764361/1199289

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cat` instead of letting R call the object's `print` method.

```
sink("data.txt")
cat(Head)
df
sink()
```

Comment: +1 Very nice. I thought I would have to do some line skipping when reading the text back into R, but the default of `read.table` assumes `#` are comment characters, and blank lines are skipped by default: `read.table("data.txt")`. Works like a charm - thanks!

Comment: Thanks again. I have a followup question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21764361/1199289. Seems my actual data set was a bit more complicated.